# PowerShell Export-CSV creates empty file

Tags: file, powershell, csv

When piping objects to `Export-Csv` the Cmdlet is always creating a file, even when the output of the pipeline is empty. Is this normal behavior?

**Code:**

```
'1' | where {$_ -ne '1'} | Export-Csv -Path $file -NoTypeInformation
```

I tried to avoid this by adding `where{$_}` but an empty file was also created:

```
'1' | where {$_ -ne '1'} | where {$_} | Export-Csv -Path $file -NoTypeInformation
```

A workaround would be:

```
'1' | where {$_ -ne '1'} | Foreach {
    if ($_) {
        Export-Csv -Path $file -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ';' -Append
    }
}
```

But using a `foreach` and an `if` seems a bit overkill. Isn't there an easier way to not end up with an empty file when no info has been piped to it? It seems strange that `Export-Csv` just creates a file even when it didn't receive anything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you're piping to Export-CSV you already took the decision to write to disk.
What about your own custom filter?

```
$File = 'C:\ByteTheDisk.csv'
Filter MaybeExport-CSV {
   if ($_)
    {
      Export-CSV -InputObject $_ -Path $File -NoTypeInformation -Append -Verbose }
    }

'1' | where {$_ -ne '1'} | MaybeExport-CSV     # No file created
'2','1' | where {$_ -ne '1'} | MaybeExport-CSV # File created for '2'
```

Comment: This is the only solution that works without adding an extra `foreach`. The other solution proposed does indeed not work on PS 4.0. Thank you for your help kamikatze. I just found it weird that `Export-Csv` created a file when it received nothing.

Comment: Note that this will happily overwrite the file as many times as there are objects coming from the pipeline, leaving you with a CSV file containing just the last object. A better option would perhaps be something like `function MaybeExport-Csv { end { if ($input) { Export-Csv ... } }`

Comment: See the edit to my comment; it's probably better to write just once to the file instead of opening and appending it over and over again.

Comment: Maybe i'm doing it wrong, but $input seems to always exist, thus we're back to square one. `using if ($input) # '1' | where {$_ -ne '1'} | MaybeExport-CSV     # Will write to disk`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
('1' | ?{$_ -ne '1'}) | Export-Csv -Path $file -NoTypeInformation
```

Note the additional brakets.

You may find you need to add Select-Object as I just checked the content of the csv and it contained the object properties rather than the values:

```
('1' | ?{$_ -ne '1'}) | Select-Object @{Name='Value';Expression={$_}} | Export-Csv -Path $file -NoTypeInformation
```

Here it is creating a file with one row:

```
(@('1','2') | ?{$_ -ne '1'}) | Select-Object @{Name='Value';Expression={$_}} | Export-Csv -Path $file -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Do you know why piping the data reacts the way it does? OP is also trying to understand the behavior as am I. Wonder if it has to do with the Export-CSV needing to having the file created for input from `Where-Object`. Since it gets none the file is not populated. $null is not being passed as that would trigger `ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed` exception.

Comment: I believe this is because $nulls will be processed at least once, which I think has been changed in later versions of powershell

Comment: In PowerShell v4 this doesn't work. `('1' | ?{$_ -ne '1'}) | Export-Csv -Path d:\tmp\file -NoTypeInformation -verbose
         VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Export-Csv" on target "d:\tmp\file".`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @kamikatze, I don't have powershell 4 to test.  Maybe your solution is the only option.